# how to delete a list within a list (i.e., a sublist) if any element of that sublist is in another list?

Tags: python, performance, list, sublist

I have a list that contains a number of sublists. For example:

```
full_list = [[1, 1, 3, 4], [3, 99, 5, 2],[2, 4, 4], [3, 4, 5, 2, 60]]
```

I also have another list, called omit.  For example:

```
omit = [99, 60, 98]
```

I want to remove the sublists inside of full_list, if *any* element in that sublist is in the omit list.  For example, I would want the resulting list to be:

```
reduced_list = [[1, 1, 3, 4], [2, 4, 4]]
```

because only these sublists do not have an element that is in the omit list.

I  am guessing that there is some easy way to pull this off with a list comprehension but I cannot get it to work.  I have tried a bunch of things: For example:

```
reduced_list = [sublist for sublist in full_list if item for sublist not in omit]
```

- this code results in an error (invalid snytax) - but I think I'm missing more than that.

Any help would be much appreciated!

p.s., The above is a simplified problem.  My end goal is to remove sublists from a very long  list (e.g., 500,000 sublists) of strings if any element (a string) of those sublists is in an "omit" list contain over 2000 strings.

Comment: You guys are awesome!  Thank you for the responses.  It worked like a charm on the longer lists.

Answer (score 5):

Use `set` and `all()`:

```
>>> omit = {99, 60, 98}
>>> full_list = [[1, 1, 3, 4], [3, 99, 5, 2],[2, 4, 4], [3, 4, 5, 2, 60]]
>>> [item for item in full_list if all(x not in omit for x in item)]
[[1, 1, 3, 4], [2, 4, 4]]
```

Main difference between this method and @alecxe's(or @Óscar López's) solution is that it `all` short-circuits and doesn't create any set or list in the memory while set-intersection returns a new set that contains all items that are common with `omit` set and it's length is checked to determine whether any item was common or not.(set-intersection happens internally at C speed so it is faster than normal python loops used in `all`)

### Timing comparison:

```
>>> import random
```

**No items intersect:**

```
>>> omit = set(random.randrange(1, 10**18) for _ in xrange(100000))
>>> full_list = [[random.randrange(10**19, 10**100) for _ in xrange(100)] for _ in xrange(1000)]

>>> %timeit [item for item in full_list if not omit & set(item)]
10 loops, best of 3: 43.3 ms per loop
>>> %timeit [x for x in full_list if not omit.intersection(x)]
10 loops, best of 3: 28 ms per loop
>>> %timeit [item for item in full_list if all(x not in omit for x in item)]
10 loops, best of 3: 65.3 ms per loop
```

**All items intersect:**

```
>>> full_list = [range(10**3) for _ in xrange(1000)]
>>> omit = set(xrange(10**3))
>>> %timeit [item for item in full_list if not omit & set(item)]
1 loops, best of 3: 148 ms per loop
>>> %timeit [x for x in full_list if not omit.intersection(x)]
1 loops, best of 3: 108 ms per loop
>>> %timeit [item for item in full_list if all(x not in omit for x in item)]
100 loops, best of 3: 1.62 ms per loop
```

**Some items intersect:**

```
>>> omit = set(xrange(1000, 10000))
>>> full_list = [range(2000) for _ in xrange(1000)]
>>> %timeit [item for item in full_list if not omit & set(item)]
1 loops, best of 3: 282 ms per loop
>>> %timeit [x for x in full_list if not omit.intersection(x)]
1 loops, best of 3: 159 ms per loop
>>> %timeit [item for item in full_list if all(x not in omit for x in item)]
1 loops, best of 3: 227 ms per loop
```

Comment: Since you're already using a set, it'll be better and faster to use the native set operations.

Comment: @Anorov I could but creating a set in the memory just for checking it's length is useless.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
full_list = [[1, 1, 3, 4], [3, 99, 5, 2], [2, 4, 4], [3, 4, 5, 2, 60]]
omit = frozenset([99, 60, 98])
reduced_list = [x for x in full_list if not omit.intersection(x)]
```

The only change that I made to the input data is that `omit` is now a set, for efficiency reasons, as it will allow us to perform a fast intersection (it's frozen because we're not going to modify it), notice that `x` doesn't have to be a set. Now the `reduced_list` variable will contain the expected value:

```
reduced_list
=> [[1, 1, 3, 4], [2, 4, 4]]
```

Comment: Better to have `omit` already as a set inside of converting it for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Anorov ahead of you :)

Comment: +1 for frozenset, it's a bit faster (check minibenchmark in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Make `omit` a set, check for intersection on each step of iteration:

```
>>> full_list = [[1, 1, 3, 4], [3, 99, 5, 2],[2, 4, 4], [3, 4, 5, 2, 60]]
>>> omit = [99, 60, 98]
>>> omit = set(omit)  # or just omit = {99, 60, 98} for python >= 2.7
>>> [item for item in full_list if not omit & set(item)]
[[1, 1, 3, 4], [2, 4, 4]]
```

FYI, better use a `frozenset` instead of a set as @Óscar López suggested. With `frozenset` it runs a bit faster:

```
import timeit


def omit_it(full_list, omit):
    return [item for item in full_list if not omit & set(item)]

print timeit.Timer('omit_it([[1, 1, 3, 4], [3, 99, 5, 2],[2, 4, 4], [3, 4, 5, 2, 60]], {99, 60, 98})',
                   'from __main__ import omit_it').timeit(10000)

print timeit.Timer('omit_it([[1, 1, 3, 4], [3, 99, 5, 2],[2, 4, 4], [3, 4, 5, 2, 60]], frozenset([99, 60, 98]))',
                   'from __main__ import omit_it').timeit(10000)
```

prints:

```
0.0334849357605
0.0319349765778
```

Comment: I was going to post a solution using `any()`, but I think this is better and more Pythonic.

Comment: Note that `omit & set(item)` won't short-circuit and will create a new set in the memory.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yeah, it's actually interesting to see what is faster..depends on the input, of course.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That's a good point, but due to the implementation `set.intersection()` may be faster even when taking into account short-circuiting from `all()`. It'd be interesting to see a benchmark.

Comment: @alecxe BTW you can use: `not omit.intersection(item)`, that is going to be faster than `not omit & set(item)`.